# Entity Framework Navigation Property preload/reuse

Tags: entity-framework, linq, eager-loading

Why is Entity Framework executing queries when I expect objects can be grabbed from EF cache?

With these simple model classes:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

public class BlogDbContext : DbContext
{
    public BlogDbContext() : base("BlogDbContext") {}

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

I profile the queries of following action

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var ctx = new BlogDbContext();

        // expecting posts are retrieved and cached by EF
        var posts = ctx.Posts.ToList();
        var blogs = ctx.Blogs.ToList();

        var wholeContent = "";

        foreach (var blog in blogs)
            foreach (var post in blog.Posts) // <- query is executed
                wholeContent += post.Content;

        return Content(wholeContent);
    }
}
```

Why doesn't EF re-use the `Post` entities which I had already grabbed with the `var posts = ctx.Posts.ToList();` statement?

**Further explanation:**

An existing application has an Excel export report. The data is grabbed via a main Linq2Sql query with a tree of includes (~20). Then it is mapped via automapper and additional data from manual caches (which previously slowed down the execution if added to the main query) is added.

Now the data is grown and SQL Server crashes when trying to execute the query with an error:

> The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan.

Lazy loading would result in >100.000 queries. So I thought I could preload all the required data with a few simple queries and let EF use the objects automatically from cache during lazy loading.

There I initial had additional problems with limits of the TSQL `IN()` clause which I solved with MoreLinq´s Batch extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have Lazy Loading enabled, EF will still reload the Collection Navigation Properties.  Probably because EF doesn't know whether you have really loaded all the Posts.  EG code like

```
   var post = db.Posts.First();
   var relatedPosts = post.Blog.Posts.ToList();
```

Would be tricky, as the Blog would have one Post already loaded, but obviously the others need to be fetched.

In any case when relying on the Change Tracker to fix-up your Navigation Properties, you should disable Lazy Loading anyway.  EG

```
using (var db = new BlogDbContext())
{
    db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    . . .
```

Comment: Ok, first snippet shows the problem EF having.But as we know that we load all required data, disabling LazyLoadingEnabled does the trick to enable EF´s "magic" binding.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have the navigation properties, look at leveraging them in your query to feed Automapper a dynamic object to map to your ViewModel/DTO rather than a top-level entity which you'd be relying on eager loading or waiting on lazy loading.

This is done by issuing a .Select() on your query. To use a simple example of extracting order details including the customer name, list of product names and quantities from order lines, and the delivery address where an Order has a reference to customer, and that customer has a delivery address, a collection of order lines, each with a product...

```
var orderDetails = dbContext.Orders
.Where(o => /* Insert criteria */)
.Select(o => new 
{
   o.OrderId,
   o.OrderNumber,
   o.Customer.CustomerId,
   CustomerName = x.Customer.FullName,
   o.Customer.DeliveryAddress, // Address entity if no further dependencies, or extract fields/relations from the Address.
   o.OrderLines.Select( ol = > new 
   {
      ol.OrderLineId,
      ProductName = ol.Product.Name,
      ol.Quantity
   }
}).ToList(); // Ready to feed into Automapper.
```

With ~20 includes your Select will undoubtedly be a bit more involved, but the idea is to feed SQL Server a query to retrieve just the data you want that you can then feed into Automapper to navigate through where any child relationships can either be flattened by EF or simplified and returned for your mapper to flesh out into the resulting models.

With growing systems you will also want to consider leveraging paging /w Skip and Take rather than ToList, or at least leveraging Take to ensure that there is a cap to the amount of data your return. ToList is a primary performance troll that I look for in EF code because its misuse can kill applications.